# Apache httpclient 4.3.3 - speed tuning

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

What I am trying to do is to collect a million urls on gigabit connection and the speed varies between 5MB/s and 12MB/s (Megabytes per second) which is much under the bandwidth maximum. The code I use:

```
    DnsResolver dnsResolver = new SystemDefaultDnsResolver();
    X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new AllowAllHostnameVerifier();
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
    RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new LaxRedirectStrategy();

    HttpConnectionFactory<HttpRoute, ManagedHttpClientConnection> connFactory= = new ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory(
                    new DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory(),
                   new DefaultHttpResponseParserFactory());

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                        .<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                        .register(
                                "https",
                                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
                                        hostnameVerifier))
                        .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                        .build();
    SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(false)
                    .setSoReuseAddress(false)
                    .setSoTimeout(15000).build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager manager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry,connFactory, dnsResolver);
     manager.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);
     manager.setMaxTotal(1000);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent("Mozilla")
                    .setConnectionManager(manager)
                    .setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy)               
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(-1).build();

    RequestConfig defaultConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
                    .setExpectContinueEnabled(false)
                    .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false)
                    .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                    .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false)
                    .setMaxRedirects(5).build();

    RequestConfig rConfig= RequestConfig.copy(defaultConfig)
                    .setSocketTimeout(15000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(-1)
                    .setConnectTimeout(15000).build();

ExecutorService  executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(640);

FutureRequestExecutionService service = new FutureRequestExecutionService(httpClient, executorService);
```

Per request configuration is:

```
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("some url");
    httpget.setConfig(rConfig);
    httpget.setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

In ResponseHandler I use the following code to consume the content:

```
 stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    final byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
```

Each url is from different domain. The machine is with 8 cores and 8GB of RAM - 64 bit linux - Debian. How to speed up this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need automatic authentication, retries, cookie management and do not mind handling redirects manually, consider using minimal HttpClient implementation. Minimal HCs are built with a minimal execution pipeline consisting of mandatory protocol interceptors only and should have the best performance characteristics with the same concurrency parameters (connection pool setup).

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.createMinimal(cm);
```

And naturally you should be wanting to re-use connection for optimal performance. This seems to go counter to what I would consider best practices.

```
httpget.setHeader("Connection", "close"); // Huh?
```

Comment: What I have now with the minimal client and the reuse param set to true is stable 11MB/s with no oscillation except a single 1 second peak of 20MB/s. Reading this : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html - yes, probably no need to set "Connection" header. With it set and unset - no change in the speed.

Comment: I ran the same code on identical as power and memory machine - and there I achieved speed above 30MB/s. So the problem is somewhere in the servers environment.

Comment: @mihz: I have to retract my statement regarding 'connection: close'. It actually makes sense if your code never hits more than one URI per host and therefore there is no benefit in keeping connections alive

Comment: @mihz: I think it is almost certain that the bottleneck is not the consumer (client) side but the producer (server) side. Target servers simply cannot generate enough traffic to saturate the channel when hitting one URI on some random hosts

Comment: ... the second machine actually was virtual and has 24 cores now and this is why I have achieved 30MB/s. I really cannot reach more than 11MB/s with 8 cores. I have played with setSoLinger and setTcpNoDelay - no result. Is there any definition for crawler speed? Probably average pages with certain size fetched per core per bandwidth? 8 cores are my limit for the project I have. Some statistics for such performance - no matter how different the configurations are?

Comment: @mihz: There are several well established web crawlers based on Apache HttpClient I personally know of. Some of their developers can also be found at dev@hc.apache.org. You might want to post your question to the list

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. You are right for the bottleneck. Will write them.